Religious movie about men seeking Jesus
This movie was set in the time of Jesus's birth (I think its a movie they used to get on Hallmark in the 90's).
It's a 90's to 2005 movie about up to 3 men traveling trying to find the baby Jesus to give him jewels as a present, one man gets tired and tells the others that they have found Jesus and to come see him. But it's not, it's just a hungry baby with his mother. So he gives his jewel away to feed him. 
Next they find this old woman and they ask for shelter but she has no money to buy oil for her oil lamps so he gives her a jewel. 
Now the ending they finally find Jesus but he is grown up and going to be crucified so they give a jewel to the guard to free Jesus but someone else is going to be crucified so they give the last jewel to the guard for this man and not Jesus. 
In the ending, Jesus speaks to him saying "When I was hungry you did not feed me, when I was in darkness you did not light my way, when I was dying you did not save me" or something like that.

The story you're describing is The Other Wise Man, and from the timeline I assume that you mean its 1985 adaptation, the TV movie The Fourth Wise Man starring Martin Sheen.

Artaban is a young Magus (Wise Man) who desires to follow the star to the birthplace of the coming King, against the counsel of his friends and family. Carrying three precious jewels to give to the baby Messiah, Artaban and his reluctant servant Orontes set off to join the caravan of the three other wise men. They miss the caravan, but Artaban continues the search for his King, always one step behind. Artaban spends much of his remaining wealth and all of his energy helping the poor and unfortunate people he meets, until at the end of his life he finally finds Jesus--at His trial! Has Artaban wasted his life in a foolish quest? Will he ever get the chance to present his gifts to the King?

In the end, Jesus actually tells Artaban the opposite of what you described ("When I was hungry, you gave me to eat" etc.), though Artaban insists he hasn't. There was also a Hallmark adaptation, but it's from 1953. Here's the preview for the 1985 version:



